# Using mlogit inside a for loop giving me an error

Tags: r, mlogit

```
for(i in 1:ncol(mldata))
{
  mlogit.mydata=mlogit(severity ~ 1|mldata[,i],data=mldata)
  mlogit[i]=summary(mlogit.mydata)$lratio$p.value
}
```

It gives the the following error: 
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[57,57] = 0

Answer (score 0):

Please add mldata details. And first argument of `mlogit` should be of type `formula`. Try the following code

```
for(i in 1:ncol(mldata))
   {
      formula <- as.formula(paste0("y ~ 1 | ", colnames(mldata)[i])
      mlogit.mydata=mlogit(formula,data=mldata)
      mlogit[i]=summary(mlogit.mydata)$lratio$p.value
   }
```